# EntityFramework 6 CODE FIRST - Dont drop database when model changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am changing my model at runtime. After that I need to recreate database according to new model. I cannot use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges because I need to prevent data loss and I don't want to drop the database. What I would need is to check for tables and delete non existing and create new ones. If some of the table changes (e.g. column has been added) it would be awesome to just alter the table. If this is not possible I can live with dropping and recreating the table. Any help ?

Comment: That is what migration is all about, check it out. google is your friend.

Comment: I have read something about migrations but in all samples you had to call some package manager commands to update database... thats something I cannot do

Comment: Assuming EF6 hasn't changed that much, you can [turn off the DatabaseInitializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, now put all of that into answer so I can give you some points ;)

Comment: You need a customized migration as described here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#enabling

Comment: why are you unable to use package manager commands?